# How should a function treat an invalid set of data?

Tags: f#, functional-programming

**How should a function treat an invalid set of data?**

I always thought of exceptions as objects within OOP.
Within FP, how should I treat invalid data?

I have examined Railway-Oriented Programming. However, I believe that technique is geared for the boundary interfaces of a system and not its core.

The following function accepts a list of plays (in order) and assigns bases based on the ordered set of plays that dictate the bases' final state:

```
let assignBases (plays:Play list) =

    let initializedBases = { First=None; Second=None; Third=None }

    match plays with
    | [] -> initializedBases
    | _  -> let move bases play = 
                match (bases, play.Hit)  with
                | { First= None; Second=None; Third=None }, Single -> { bases with First=  Some play.Player }
                | { First= None; Second=None; Third=None }, Double -> { bases with Second= Some play.Player }
                | { First= None; Second=None; Third=None }, Triple -> { bases with Third=  Some play.Player }

                | { First= firstPlayer; Second=None; Third=None }, Single -> { First=Some play.Player; Second=firstPlayer; Third=None }
                | { First= firstPlayer; Second=None; Third=None }, Double -> { First=None; Second=Some play.Player; Third=firstPlayer }
                | { First= firstPlayer; Second=None; Third=None }, Triple -> { First=None; Second=None; Third=Some play.Player }

                | { First= None; Second=firstPlayer; Third=None }, Single -> { First=Some play.Player; Second=None; Third=firstPlayer }
                | { First= None; Second=firstPlayer; Third=None }, Double -> { First=None; Second=Some play.Player; Third=None }
                | { First= None; Second=firstPlayer; Third=None }, Triple -> { First=None; Second=None; Third=Some play.Player }

                | { First= None; Second=None; Third=firstPlayer }, Single -> { First=Some play.Player; Second=None; Third=None }
                | { First= None; Second=None; Third=firstPlayer }, Double -> { First=None; Second=Some play.Player; Third=None }
                | { First= None; Second=None; Third=firstPlayer }, Triple -> { First=None; Second=None; Third=Some play.Player }

                | { First= secondPlayer; Second=firstPlayer; Third=None }, Single -> { First=Some play.Player; Second=secondPlayer; Third=firstPlayer }
                | { First= secondPlayer; Second=firstPlayer; Third=None }, Double -> { First=None; Second=Some play.Player; Third=secondPlayer }
                | { First= secondPlayer; Second=firstPlayer; Third=None }, Triple -> { First=None; Second=None; Third=Some play.Player }

                | { First= None; Second=secondPlayer; Third=firstPlayer }, Single -> { First=Some play.Player; Second=None; Third=secondPlayer }
                | { First= None; Second=secondPlayer; Third=firstPlayer }, Double -> { First=None; Second=Some play.Player; Third=None }
                | { First= None; Second=secondPlayer; Third=firstPlayer }, Triple -> { First=None; Second=None; Third=Some play.Player }

                | { First= secondPlayer; Second=None; Third=firstPlayer }, Single -> { First=Some play.Player; Second=secondPlayer; Third=None }
                | { First= secondPlayer; Second=None; Third=firstPlayer }, Double -> { First=None; Second=Some play.Player; Third=secondPlayer }
                | { First= secondPlayer; Second=None; Third=firstPlayer }, Triple -> { First=None; Second=None; Third=Some play.Player }

                | _ -> initializedBases // Haven't identified any other cases...
```

**Consideration:**

When writing a property-based test, I discovered an anomaly within my function:

*What happens when you have the same player assigned to multiple bases?*

My property test identified this case scenario.

**Question:**

What is the current practice of managing invalid data fed to a function?

I think I understand that within a real system, the invalid data should fail at validation before hitting this function within the domain model.

But what if some how invalid data does reach a function that has strict rules?

**Do I throw an exception?**

**Should the function have additional logic to manage exceptions without throwing an exception?**

My property test is the following:

```
module Properties

open Model
open FsCheck
open FsCheck.Xunit

[<Property(QuietOnSuccess = true)>]
let ``Any hit results in a base beeing filled`` () =

    let values = Arb.generate<Play list> |> Gen.suchThat (fun plays -> plays.Length > 0)
                                         |> Arb.fromGen
    Prop.forAll values <| fun plays ->

        // Test
        let actual = plays |> assignBases

        // Verify
        actual <> { First=None; Second=None; Third=None }
```

The failure was this:

```
Test Name:  Properties.Any hit results in a base beeing filled
Test FullName:  Properties.Any hit results in a base beeing filled

Result Message: 
FsCheck.Xunit.PropertyFailedException : 
Falsifiable, after 37 tests (0 shrinks) (StdGen (543307172,296154334)):
Original:
<null>
[{Player = Brian;
  Hit = Double;}; {Player = Scott;
                   Hit = Triple;}; {Player = Cherice;
                                    Hit = Double;}; {Player = Brian;
                                                     Hit = Single;};
 {Player = Cherice;
  Hit = Double;}; {Player = Brian;
                   Hit = Double;}; {Player = Cherice;
                                    Hit = Triple;}; {Player = Brian;
                                                     Hit = Single;};
 {Player = Cherice;
  Hit = Double;}; {Player = Brian;
                   Hit = Single;}; {Player = Cherice;
                                    Hit = Triple;}; {Player = Brian;
                                                     Hit = Single;};
 {Player = Brian;
  Hit = Triple;}; {Player = Cherice;
                   Hit = Triple;}; {Player = Brian;
                                    Hit = Double;}; {Player = Brian;
                                                     Hit = Triple;};
 {Player = Cherice;
  Hit = Triple;}; {Player = Cherice;
                   Hit = Single;}; {Player = Scott;
                                    Hit = Single;}; {Player = Scott;
                                                     Hit = Single;};
 {Player = Scott;
  Hit = Double;}]
```

**Summary of failure:**

Specifically, my pattern match logic within the function under test did not account for the same player assigned to more than one base.

The entire code is here:

```
module Model

(*Types*)
type Position =
    | First
    | Second
    | Third 

type Player =
    | Scott
    | Brian
    | Cherice

type Hit =
    | Single
    | Double
    | Triple

type Play = { Player: Player; Hit: Hit }

type Bases = { 
    First:Player  option
    Second:Player option
    Third:Player  option
}

(*Functions*)
let assignBases (plays:Play list) =

    let initializedBases = { First=None; Second=None; Third=None }

    match plays with
    | [] -> initializedBases
    | _  -> let move bases play = 
                match (bases, play.Hit)  with
                | { First= None; Second=None; Third=None }, Single -> { bases with First=  Some play.Player }
                | { First= None; Second=None; Third=None }, Double -> { bases with Second= Some play.Player }
                | { First= None; Second=None; Third=None }, Triple -> { bases with Third=  Some play.Player }

                | { First= firstPlayer; Second=None; Third=None }, Single -> { First=Some play.Player; Second=firstPlayer; Third=None }
                | { First= firstPlayer; Second=None; Third=None }, Double -> { First=None; Second=Some play.Player; Third=firstPlayer }
                | { First= firstPlayer; Second=None; Third=None }, Triple -> { First=None; Second=None; Third=Some play.Player }

                | { First= None; Second=firstPlayer; Third=None }, Single -> { First=Some play.Player; Second=None; Third=firstPlayer }
                | { First= None; Second=firstPlayer; Third=None }, Double -> { First=None; Second=Some play.Player; Third=None }
                | { First= None; Second=firstPlayer; Third=None }, Triple -> { First=None; Second=None; Third=Some play.Player }

                | { First= None; Second=None; Third=firstPlayer }, Single -> { First=Some play.Player; Second=None; Third=None }
                | { First= None; Second=None; Third=firstPlayer }, Double -> { First=None; Second=Some play.Player; Third=None }
                | { First= None; Second=None; Third=firstPlayer }, Triple -> { First=None; Second=None; Third=Some play.Player }

                | { First= secondPlayer; Second=firstPlayer; Third=None }, Single -> { First=Some play.Player; Second=secondPlayer; Third=firstPlayer }
                | { First= secondPlayer; Second=firstPlayer; Third=None }, Double -> { First=None; Second=Some play.Player; Third=secondPlayer }
                | { First= secondPlayer; Second=firstPlayer; Third=None }, Triple -> { First=None; Second=None; Third=Some play.Player }

                | { First= None; Second=secondPlayer; Third=firstPlayer }, Single -> { First=Some play.Player; Second=None; Third=secondPlayer }
                | { First= None; Second=secondPlayer; Third=firstPlayer }, Double -> { First=None; Second=Some play.Player; Third=None }
                | { First= None; Second=secondPlayer; Third=firstPlayer }, Triple -> { First=None; Second=None; Third=Some play.Player }

                | { First= secondPlayer; Second=None; Third=firstPlayer }, Single -> { First=Some play.Player; Second=secondPlayer; Third=None }
                | { First= secondPlayer; Second=None; Third=firstPlayer }, Double -> { First=None; Second=Some play.Player; Third=secondPlayer }
                | { First= secondPlayer; Second=None; Third=firstPlayer }, Triple -> { First=None; Second=None; Third=Some play.Player }

                | _ -> initializedBases // Haven't identified any other cases...

            (initializedBases, plays) ||> List.fold (fun bases play -> 
                                                         play |> move bases)
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on the recommendations posted, I have made some updates to my model:

I added a Status type to denote the state of data being processed:

```
type Status =
    | Valid of Bases
    | Invalid of Play list
```

I then applied this status to the bases value such that expected state is marked as "Valid" and unexpected is marked as "Invalid":

```
let assignBases (plays:Play list) =

    let initializedBases = { First=None; Second=None; Third=None }

    match plays with
    | [] -> Valid initializedBases
    | _  -> let move bases play = 
                match (bases, play.Hit)  with
                | Valid { First= None; Second=None; Third=None }, Single -> Valid { First=  Some play.Player; Second=None; Third=None }
                | Valid { First= None; Second=None; Third=None }, Double -> Valid { First=None; Second= Some play.Player; Third=None }
                | Valid { First= None; Second=None; Third=None }, Triple -> Valid { First=None; Second=None; Third=  Some play.Player }

                | Valid { First= firstPlayer; Second=None; Third=None }, Single -> Valid { First=Some play.Player; Second=firstPlayer; Third=None }
                | Valid { First= firstPlayer; Second=None; Third=None }, Double -> Valid { First=None; Second=Some play.Player; Third=firstPlayer }
                | Valid { First= firstPlayer; Second=None; Third=None }, Triple -> Valid { First=None; Second=None; Third=Some play.Player }

                | Valid { First= None; Second=firstPlayer; Third=None }, Single -> Valid { First=Some play.Player; Second=None; Third=firstPlayer }
                | Valid { First= None; Second=firstPlayer; Third=None }, Double -> Valid { First=None; Second=Some play.Player; Third=None }
                | Valid { First= None; Second=firstPlayer; Third=None }, Triple -> Valid { First=None; Second=None; Third=Some play.Player }

                | Valid { First= None; Second=None; Third=firstPlayer }, Single -> Valid { First=Some play.Player; Second=None; Third=None }
                | Valid { First= None; Second=None; Third=firstPlayer }, Double -> Valid { First=None; Second=Some play.Player; Third=None }
                | Valid { First= None; Second=None; Third=firstPlayer }, Triple -> Valid { First=None; Second=None; Third=Some play.Player }

                | Valid { First= secondPlayer; Second=firstPlayer; Third=None }, Single -> Valid { First=Some play.Player; Second=secondPlayer; Third=firstPlayer }
                | Valid { First= secondPlayer; Second=firstPlayer; Third=None }, Double -> Valid { First=None; Second=Some play.Player; Third=secondPlayer }
                | Valid { First= secondPlayer; Second=firstPlayer; Third=None }, Triple -> Valid { First=None; Second=None; Third=Some play.Player }

                | Valid { First= None; Second=secondPlayer; Third=firstPlayer }, Single -> Valid { First=Some play.Player; Second=None; Third=secondPlayer }
                | Valid { First= None; Second=secondPlayer; Third=firstPlayer }, Double -> Valid { First=None; Second=Some play.Player; Third=None }
                | Valid { First= None; Second=secondPlayer; Third=firstPlayer }, Triple -> Valid { First=None; Second=None; Third=Some play.Player }

                | Valid { First= secondPlayer; Second=None; Third=firstPlayer }, Single -> Valid { First=Some play.Player; Second=secondPlayer; Third=None }
                | Valid { First= secondPlayer; Second=None; Third=firstPlayer }, Double -> Valid { First=None; Second=Some play.Player; Third=secondPlayer }
                | Valid { First= secondPlayer; Second=None; Third=firstPlayer }, Triple -> Valid { First=None; Second=None; Third=Some play.Player }

                | _ -> Invalid plays // Haven't identified any other cases...

            (Valid initializedBases, plays) ||> List.fold (fun bases play -> play |> move bases)
```

Comment: Maybe you need a rule that says you cannot bat if you are on base. Or you can look at this as two queues, one for the batters and one for the players on the bases. Or you can modify player to have more states than jus the three of being on base, e.g. base, batting, bench, fielding.

Answer (score 4):

Throwing an exception vs returning an error state depends on what action you want to take during failure and where the data came from.  The general question of whether or not to throw an exception has been discussed many times on stack overflow.

If the data is from the user then returning an object that contains success/failure is preferred.  You don't want to crash on the user.  If the data was generated by the system or developer then an exception is preferred.  Exceptions will give you a stack dump that you can investigate.  More generally if your program gets into a state it can't recover from then throw an exception.

Specifically for `F#`, returning Option is good enough for simple cases.  More complex cases will need discriminated unions which can themselves contain objects or just enumerations.  Pattern matching is great for error handling in F#.

Answer (score 3):

I think these questions are close to the line of being subjective but not over so take these answers more with `this is what I would do` rather than `this is the gospel according to F#`.

> How should a function treat an invalid set of data?

One way I look at data is that it has two worlds, one that comes in from the environment and is `unsanitized` an one that has been `sanitized` and should not lead to errors. So to get the data from unsanitized to sanitized you check it, if it passes you can use it, if not reject it with the reasons. If you did everything correct then you should not get errors.

> What is the current practice of managing invalid data fed to a function?

That is a `it depends` but relying on the [Option type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/options-%5Bfsharp%5D) is always a good first fall back option.

For a more in-depth read: [Tackling the Awkward Squad: monadic input/output, concurrency, exceptions, and foreign-language calls in Haskell](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/marktoberdorf/mark.pdf) by Simon Peyton Jones

After reading this you will start to understand why I keep dropping Haskell hints.

> But what if some how invalid data does reach a function that has strict rules?

In short don't let it happen. If it does it is not the functions fault but the fault of the programmer. That line of reasoning is recursive so where does it get you?

> Do I throw an exception?

Why? I avoid exceptions every time I can unless I am doing some documentation or have to interface with something that wants an exception. Again I try to stay with total functions.

> Should the function have additional logic to manage exceptions without throwing an exception?

Again avoid exceptions. F# is not OO and not OCaml. Yes using exceptions in OCaml is customary because of the signifigant differences between the way F# and OCaml handle exceptions.

So as I noted in the comment, I see the answer to your problem as not patching your function, but changing your model, then changing the functions to match the model.

Comment: Thanks Guy Coder. I'm going to let the community vote on the answers before I choose one.

Comment: This is a good approach, but IMO it doesn't hurt to cover some easily detectable cases that should never happen – i.e. "invalid data does reach" – via `failwith`, `invalidOp`, or 'invalidArg'. If there is some minor slip on implementing or refactoring, failing fast can help to locate it quickly.

Comment: @Vandroiy Are you suggesting something like [assertions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_(software_development)) and [Hoare logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic)? I too find them useful. As we know there is no single acceptable answer to this.

Comment: @GuyCoder Ah, yes, those are assertions, and I should've included the F# `assert` keyword. (Though this F# feature isn't my favorite; it takes attention when using multiple assemblies, has super weird semantics, and is often a premature optimization.)

Comment: @Vandroiy I am glad you added a different answer as it gives me insight into how others think about these problems.

Answer (score 2):

This is a matter of programming style and depends on the type of problem you're working on, and [Guy Coder's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37195328/4191347) is a good way to think about it. But I believe that, before going into the details of error cases, it is useful to divide faulty input into the following three categories:

- Values that are unusual, but part of the problem domain
- Values that are invalid, but will be detected quickly once the program runs
- Values that break specification but may not be detected quickly

Here's how I treat them:

**Unusual values in the program's domain** should be modeled as a part of the problem a function is solving, i.e. as a discriminated union or other normal return type. If it's part of the problem, there's no real difference to other things the function is doing.

**Invalid values that a test will reveal right away** are unimportant. Their origin will be found and repaired as soon as the program runs. There's little gain in spending your attention on these.

**Subtle breaches of the specification** are *the absolutely critical cases to think about if the program is to be robust*. Pepper these with `failwith`, `invalidArg`, `invalidOp`, assertions (if all code that can cause them is tested with a debug compile of the assembly), or other exceptions that *will terminate the program*, because *you don't know what the program is doing anymore*!